# RecyclerView неправильно отображает item

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

В моем приложении есть тест. В каждом из вопросов можно выбрать один из 5 вариантов ответа. При этом выбранный вариант выделяется серым цветом(если до этого был выделен другой, то этот другой обесцвечивается) и информация о ответе передается в базу данных SQLite. Конкретно эта часть работает нормально. Но если прокрутить RecyclerView, в других вопросах почему то появляются выделенные серым светом варианты, а кое где даже несколько выделенных. При этом в базе данных эти ответы не появляются.

Holder:

```
private class QuestionHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private Question mQuestion;

        private TextView mQuestionText;
        private ImageView mQuestionImage;
        private TextView mAnswer1;
        private TextView mAnswer2;
        private TextView mAnswer3;
        private TextView mAnswer4;
        private TextView mAnswer5;
        private LinearLayout mButtonAn1;
        private LinearLayout mButtonAn2;
        private LinearLayout mButtonAn3;
        private LinearLayout mButtonAn4;
        private LinearLayout mButtonAn5;

        public QuestionHolder(View v, int part) {
            super(v);
            mQuestionText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_text);
            mQuestionImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.question_image);
            mUserAnswer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_answer);
                    mAnswer1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An1);
                    mAnswer2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An2);
                    mAnswer3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An3);
                    mAnswer4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An4);
                    mAnswer5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An5);

                    mButtonAn1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An1_Button);
                    mButtonAn2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An2_Button);
                    mButtonAn3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An3_Button);
                    mButtonAn4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An4_Button);
                    mButtonAn5 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.An5_Button);
            }
        }

        public void bind(final Question question) {
            mQuestion = question;
            SubjectParent.getSubjectSingleton(getActivity(), SUBJECT).updateQuestion(mQuestion, TEST);
            mQuestionText.setText(mQuestion.getText());
            mQuestionImage.setImageBitmap(mQuestion.getBitmap())
                    mAnswer1.setText(mQuestion.getAnswer1());
                    mAnswer2.setText(mQuestion.getAnswer2());
                    mAnswer3.setText(mQuestion.getAnswer3());
                    mAnswer4.setText(mQuestion.getAnswer4());
                    mAnswer5.setText(mQuestion.getAnswer5());

                    if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer() != null) {
                        if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mQuestion.getAnswer1())) {
                            mButtonAn1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                        }
                        if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mQuestion.getAnswer2())) {
                            mButtonAn2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                        }
                        if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mQuestion.getAnswer3())) {
                            mButtonAn3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                        }
                        if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mQuestion.getAnswer4())) {
                            mButtonAn4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                        }
                        if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mQuestion.getAnswer5())) {
                            mButtonAn5.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                        }
                    }

                    mButtonAn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            updateUserAnswer();
                            mButtonAn1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                            mQuestion.setUserAnswer(mQuestion.getAnswer1());
                            SubjectParent.getSubjectSingleton(getActivity(), SUBJECT).updateQuestion(mQuestion, TEST);
                        }
                    });
                    mButtonAn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            updateUserAnswer();
                            mButtonAn2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                            mQuestion.setUserAnswer(mQuestion.getAnswer2());
                            SubjectParent.getSubjectSingleton(getActivity(), SUBJECT).updateQuestion(mQuestion, TEST);
                        }
                    });
                    mButtonAn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            updateUserAnswer();
                            mButtonAn3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                            mQuestion.setUserAnswer(mQuestion.getAnswer3());
                            SubjectParent.getSubjectSingleton(getActivity(), SUBJECT).updateQuestion(mQuestion, TEST);
                        }
                    });
                    mButtonAn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            updateUserAnswer();
                            mButtonAn4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                            mQuestion.setUserAnswer(mQuestion.getAnswer4());
                            SubjectParent.getSubjectSingleton(getActivity(), SUBJECT).updateQuestion(mQuestion, TEST);
                        }
                    });
                    mButtonAn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            updateUserAnswer();
                            mButtonAn5.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                            mQuestion.setUserAnswer(mQuestion.getAnswer5());
                            SubjectParent.getSubjectSingleton(getActivity(), SUBJECT).updateQuestion(mQuestion, TEST);
                        }
                    });

        private void updateUserAnswer() {
            mButtonAn1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
            mButtonAn2.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
            mButtonAn3.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
            mButtonAn4.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
            mButtonAn5.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
        }
```

}

Adapter:

```
public class QuestionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QuestionHolder> {
    private List<Question> mQuestions;

    public QuestionAdapter(List<Question> questions) {
        mQuestions = questions;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public QuestionHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_a_question, viewGroup, false);
        return new QuestionHolder(v, viewType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull QuestionHolder questionHolder, int i) {
        Question question = mQuestions.get(i);
        questionHolder.bind(question);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mQuestions.size();
    }

    public void setQuestions(List<Question> questions) {
        mQuestions = questions;
    }
}
```

Я уже проходилась с отладчиком по коду и вот эта часть не вызывается перед появлением неправильных item, хотя, по идее, по другому они никак не могут изменить цвет:

```
if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer() != null) {
                    if (mQuestion.getUserAnswer().equals(mQuestion.getAnswer1())) {
                        mButtonAn1.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGray));
                    }
```

Также если перезайти в активность, ошибка исчезает. Я не вижу других вариантов, кроме неправильной переработки RecyclerView item'ов. Буду благодарна за любые догадки, что это может быть или советы, как можно реализовать такой функционал по другому.

Comment: дело в том, что айтемы в recyclerview переиспользуются при прокрутке и вполне может быть ситуация, когда переиспользуется айтем с выделением в позиции, которую не надо выделять. При выводе каждого айтема нужно не только закрашивать его в цвет выделения (серый) если его надо выделить, но и в цвет общего списка, если выделить его не надо, то есть условие должно быть для обоих вариантов - `if (закрасить) {серый} else {белый}`/ Для каждого айтема должен быть однозначно установлен цвет этого айтема, а не только цвет закрашенного.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, все работает! Эта глупая ошибка застопорила меня на месте на несколько дней. Впредь буду знать.